# How to insert values to the SQLite database from R.Data?

Tags: sql, r, database, rsqlite

I am trying to insert data to `sqlite` database from R `data.frame` but I failed.

Here is the code in R studio I used.

So there two loops using which I'm trying to load all `dbf` files listed in the specified folders (working directory). And then I'm trying to insert data from R `data.frame` (`df[[1]]`) to the `sqlite` database (I have already created it) by `sqldf` or by `dbExecute` functions.

In case of `dbExecute` the function cannot read table from R `data.frame` (in this case `df[[1]]`).

In case of `sqldf` the function doesn't see `all_banks` table created earlier in the database.

Any ideas of how to handle this problem?
Thank to all.

```
library(sqldf)
library(DBI)
library(foreign)
library("RSQLite")



setwd("F:~/Data")
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "banks.db")
for(path in c("F:~/123-20190901",
          "F:~/123-20190801")){
  setwd(path)
  ldf <- list()
  listdbf <- dir(pattern = "*.DBF")
  for (k in 1:length(listdbf)){
     ldf[[k]] <- read.dbf(listdbf[k])
     }

  df1 <- ldf[[1]]
  df2 <- ldf[[2]]
  dbExecute(con, "insert into all_banks select DT, REGN, name_b from df1")
  sqldf("insert into all_banks select DT, REGN, name_b from df1")
}
dbDisconnect(con)

Error: no such table: df1
Error: no such table: all_banks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, `sqldf` and `dbExecute` are two different processes where the former works in local environment and latter works in an external database (albeit with noted exceptions).

Per [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html),

> sqldf is an R package for running SQL statements on R data frames, optimized for convenience.

Therefore, `sqldf`, runs on R data frames in *local* environment. By default, `sqldf` is not used to make changes to a persistent, *external* database. Technically, it runs an in-memory SQLite database which does not save after R session. Consequently, if *all_banks* is not a data frame in global environment, it will not be recognized by `sqldf`. With that said, there is an [advanced way](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html#example-12.-combine-two-files-in-permanent-database) of using `sqldf` with a permanent SQLite database. But below solution is arguably easier.

---

Per [docs](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/DBI/html/dbExecute.html), `DBI::dbExecute`

> Executes a statement and returns the number of rows affected.

With first argument:

> `conn`:          A DBIConnection object, as returned by `dbConnect()`.

Therefore, `dbExecute` runs commands on an *external* database and within its scope does not use *local* environment objects. Consequently, if *df1* is not a table in database, it will not be recognized by `dbExecute`.

---

**Solution**

To resolve your database append needs, simply use DBI's [`dbWriteTable`](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/DBI/html/dbWriteTable.html) which pushes a local R data frame into an external database table (assuming same structure on both end points unless using `overwrite=TRUE`). Such changes to table will remain permanent even after closing database connection or R session.

```
dbWriteTable(con, name="all_banks", value=df1, append=TRUE)
```